# Using a different Connection within Doctrine_Table in symfony 1.4 / sfMasterSlavePlugin

Tags: php, symfony1, connection, doctrine

In my symfony project i'm working with doctrine for my data models. Also i have the sfMasterSlavePlugin installed to use different connections for different kinds of queries (writes vs. reads).

Because of the small delay in mysql's replication my code is failing to fetch a freshly inserted record. To get around this problem i want to force the master connection for this read query. But also i want to have the context of Doctrine_Table to work with my model in a proper way.

Is there a way to force the master connection within a Doctrine_Table method ? And how can this be done ?

My class currently looks like this:

```
class UserTable extends Doctrine_Table
{

public static function getInstance()
{
    return Doctrine_Core::getTable('User');
}

public function fetchByLoginFromMaster($login)
{
    $q = $this->createQuery()
                ->from('User')
                ->where('login = ?', $login)
                ->fetchOne();

    return $q;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is this:

```
public function fetchByLoginFromMaster($login)
{
  $conn = ProjectConfiguration::getActive()->getMasterConnection();
  $q = Doctrine_Query::create($conn)
                ->from('User')
                ->where('login = ?', $login)
                ->fetchOne();
  return $q;
}
```

Comment: Hi John,

thanks for your reply. I tried out your suggestion. $conn now contains the master connection, which i testet with var_dump($conn->getName()).

But still, the query is using the slave connection. I double-checked this by changing the password of the slave connection, which caused the request to fail.

Thanks,
Stephan

Answer (score 0):

i also tried to set the connection explicitly to master before doing the query. But again, the slave connection was used to execute the query.

I tried the following:

```
public function fetchByLoginFromMaster($login)
{
    $masterConn = ProjectConfiguration::getActive()->getMasterConnection();

    $this->setConnection($masterConn);

    $q = $this->createQuery()
                ->from('User')
                ->where('login = ?', $login)
                ->fetchOne();

    return $q;
}
```

Thank you,
Stephan